# Depress a button and wait for a second button input = Game move : Issue

Tags: python, button, tkinter, click, self

Ok I am having a problem with my code,  I know the move I am trying to do works but i cant figure out out to make let you select which move in which situation.

This is an example of one of my buttons, There are 25 all together

```
self.B00 = Button(frame)
self.B00.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.clicked)
self.B00.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.B00.config(height=8, width=16)
```

***** This is my button click move definition ***** This is where I i feel I am having the problem. you click B00 then should be able to click B04 and it place an X in B04 and move the row to the left.  What is happening is when I click B04 it is starting the if statement on that button instead of finishing the original if statement. So nothing happens.  How do I fix this.

```
def clicked(self, event):
    if event.widget == self.B00:
        print("You can select B04 or B40")
        if event.widget == self.B04:
            self.userMoveLeft(4)
        elif event.widget == self.B40:
            self.userMoveUp(20)

    if event.widget == self.B04:
        if event.widget == self.B00:
            self.userMoveRight(0)
        elif event.widget == self.B44:
            self.userMoveUp(24)
```

This is my actual move left definition

```
def userMoveLeft(self, pos):
    # Is this a valid move?
    if self.board[pos] == " " or self.board[pos] == "X" or self.board[pos] == "O":
        # Record the players move...]
        self.board[pos - 4] = self.board[pos - 3]
        self.board[pos - 3] = self.board[pos - 2]
        self.board[pos - 2] = self.board[pos - 1]
        self.board[pos - 1] = self.board[pos]
        self.board[pos] = "X"
        # Then redraw the board!
        self.redrawBoard()
```

So what shoudl happen is when the user clicks button B00 He should have a choice to click B04 or B40,  What I feel is happening is If you click B00 then Click B04 it is stopping my if statement and moving to the if statement on the button B04 and starting the if statement over instead of placing the X on B04 like it should.

This will be a game of QUIXO if you have ever played.

I do know that if I take out the If statements on my where i call my self.userMoveLeft or whatever the move itself does work so my problem is in the middle definition marked with a *****

I just wanted to add I am new to programming so excuse me if I dont fully understand

I also am thinking that it would be nice to be able to keep the button held down  while the user makes their 2nd pick board piece. Seems like you should be able to make event.widget == self.B00 a Depressed button until you pick self.B04 to make your move then B00 is no longer held down.

All of this is made with Python using the tkinter module

Thank you for your help.

***EDIT***

I was wondering if something like
    def clicked(self, event, event2):
        if event.widget == self.B00:
            print("You can select B04 or B40")
            if event2.widget == self.B04:
                self.userMoveLeft(4)
            elif event2.widget == self.B40:
                self.userMoveUp(20)

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
def clicked(self, event):
    if event.widget == self.B00:
        print("You can select B04 or B40")
        if event.widget == self.B04:
            self.userMoveLeft(4)
        elif event.widget == self.B40:
            self.userMoveUp(20)
```

after you do the `print` statement, none of the other code will be executed.  `event.widget` has the value `self.B00` or we wouldn't be executing this code. The nested `if` statements will not be executed, since they require `event.widget` to have some other value.  You are apparently thinking that when the user clicks button 4 or button 40, the value of `event.widget` will change, but this is not so.  What will happen is that `self.click` will be called another time, with a different value of `event.widget`.

When you execute a callback like `self.click`, it runs to completion.  You are not able to process other events until it finishes.  So your mental model of what is happening is incorrect. You click button 0, and `self.click` runs.  Now, when you push button 4, `self.click` runs again.  Suppose that self.click were a long-running function, and you pressed button 4 before the first call of `self.click` had finished running.  The second button press would be added to the event queue, and the second button press wouldn't be processed until the first call of `self.click` finished running.

Perhaps what you want to do is to disable all buttons but button 4 and button 40 when button 0 is pressed.  I am not familiar with this game, so I don't know if this is a good idea or not.

EDIT: To disable button 0, you can use

```
self.B000.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

to enable it again, use

```
self.B000.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

What I would try first is to have the callbacks disable all buttons immediately (write a function called `disableButtons` or something like that) and then enable only the buttons you need.  Disabling 40 buttons should be so fast you won't notice it.  When you disable the button, it will be grayed out, or dimmed, so that it should be obvious to the user which ones he's allowed to press.

If the games rules accommodate this approach, I would recommend a having a `dict` showing which buttons are allowed after a particular choice.  For instance

```
allowed[self.B000] = [self.B004,self.B040]
```

then your callback could start something like

```
def clicked(self, event):
    disableButtons()
    for button in allowed[event.widget]:
        button.configure(state = tk.NORMAL)
```

Comment: That would actually be perfect do you have an idea of how to disable all buttons but those, as I said I am new to programming and I have pieced this together being self taught so I really appreciate the help. When you disable all the other buttons and press 04 or 40 it should place an X in that spot I can handle the rest moving the columns  Thank you again

Comment: You won't be able to have two events in the same callback, as I tried to explain above.  I added some more details about enabling and disabling widgets.   Without knowing the game rules I can't go into it any deeper.  (I looked up the game on the Web, but the explanation didn't make much sense to me.)   If this answer solves your problem, please accept it so others will know it's been resolved.